# JavaFX background thread task should play music in a loop as background thread

Tags: audio, javafx

I made a little game, where always background music should be played in a loop.
I took this code but that does not work. First it plays as expected, then it begins to overloop and it is impossible to listen to. 
What did I make wrong?

```
final Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            int s = INDEFINITE;
            AudioClip audio = new AudioClip(getClass().getResource("aquarium.mp3").toExternalForm());
            audio.setVolume(0.5f);
            audio.setCycleCount(s);
            audio.play();
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
```

Comment: It would be very important for me, does anyone know a solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my mp3-File. I took a wav-File, and everything worked.